# @Enterprise Library Unity property inject

Tags: properties, unity-container, enterprise, code-injection

I'm a fresher with the enterprise library. I want to ask some questions and any help will be appreciate.

1、 How to deploy  inject an instance property.

```
public class MyObject
{
   public MyObject(string Title)
   {
      ///...
   }
   public MyObject(InjectObject injectObject)
   {
      ///...
   }
   public InjectObject InjectObject{get;set;}
   public List<string> MyList {get;set;}
   public string Title {get;set;}
} 

Now I know how to inject the default value to the title property. But how to do 
with 
the InjectObject and the MyList.

<register type="IMyObject" mapTo="MyObject">
   <property name="Title" value="MyFirstObject">
   </property>
   //But how to assign or instance the InjectObject and the MyList
</register>
But how to assign or instance the InjectObject and the MyList

 <register type="IMyObject" MapTo=“MyObject”>
  <constructor>
     <param type="string" name="title" value="MyFirstObject"/>
  </constructor>
```

2、 How to deliver a class instance to the constructor
   and I know how to assign a string value to the constructor. But how to transfer
   a class    instance.

How can I assign a class instance to the constructor and How if i have two constructor method to deploy.

Thank you for your help. 
Best Regards.

Daivd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, prefer constructor injection over property injection.

To inject the type to the constructor, you use the `<dependency [name=""] />` attribute.

For example:

```
<register type="IMyObject" MapTo=“MyObject”>
    <constructor>
        <param name="injectObject">
            <dependency />
        </param>
    </constructor>
<register>

<register type="InjectObject" />
```

UPDATE:

To add an array as the injection value you need to configure something like this:

```
<param name="parmName">  
    <array>  
        <value value="firstValue" />  
        <dependency />  
        <value value="some other value" />  
    </array>  
</param>
```

Check out the [Unity configure schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660914%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) for all the detail on how to do this.

Comment: Hi Rory, Thank you for you advice, and I can inject the class instance property successfully. Could you give me some idea how to inject the list property or the arraylist property. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Rory. Now I can interact with the class instance priperty and the array.